# Multiple Windows using window.open()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So as we all know if you click on a submit button that has embedded in it a `onClick(windown.open(...))` this opens a new window with all the lovely attributes you specify. However if then proceed to click on the parent window and again click on the 'submit' button without closing the previous popup window, then that same window is overwritten with the new data.

Now I need a way for that `window.open()` script to create new windows every time it is clicked. SO in theory I could click the parent "submit" button 2 consecutive times and have 2 different child windows appear.

I'm sure it's trivial but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this,it will create new child, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DX86L/1/)

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
 window.open(yoururl,"_blank",'PopUp',randomnumber,'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
```

Comment: its working in javascript but i am creating asp.net application.Random number have generated but while passing the value in window.open function its not working.

Comment: Rather than using a random number, you should just use a counter, then the names can be guaranteed to be unique. It's also a much simpler algorithm and much more efficient: `window.open(yoururl,"_blank",'PopUp'+ ++counter +'…')`.

Comment: This answer is bugged out the wazoo and only works by coincidence:
1. window.open() takes at most 4 parameters: url, name, options, replace.  You are calling it wrongly, with too many parameters and misaligned parameters. 2. Neither the random number name nor the window options are working as you intended.
3. "_blank" by itself means "open in a new window"
4. A random number between 1 and 100 would not be reliable for uniqueness (although in your answer due to bugs #1 and #2 it doesn't get used for that anyway).

Answer (score 22):

Give each window a [new window name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).

```
window.open(url, WindowName)
```

Comment: Thanks,But its not working.Using that i can open only a single window

Comment: Did you give each one a unique name? AKA, increment it with a counter.

Comment: You can also use an empty string, it seems. On my Firefox, it's creating a new window everytime.

Comment: Use "_blank" as the `WindowName` and it'll always open a new window.

Answer (score 3):

Check this this might help you to open new window every time.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery demo</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(event) {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
});

</script>
<input type=button name="btn" id="btn">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See your right that that code does open a window, however if you keep that child window open, and reclick the button on the parent window, a new child windown is NOT spawned. It simply refreshes the same child window. I need to be able to create multiple child windows all running simultaneously.

Comment: @Percia Nancy:-Nope I tried it in chrome and firefox browser it is opening a new page.

Comment: yeah its opening new page.I have to open a new window multiple times for multiple clicks.

Comment: from Mozilla Documentation: To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special value _blank for strWindowName. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 3):

`window.open(url, '', 'width=1000, height=500')`

then, you get new popup every time to click popupbutton.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the browser was blocking the pop-up window. I just allowed it to open the pop-up window.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

You need to disable Track outbound links which will open only one window. Add the following javascript code to index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicky_custom = clicky_custom || {};
  clicky_custom.outbound_disable = 1;
</script>
```

Comment: This answer seems unrelated to the question, it is something to do with the "Clicky web analytics" product.