# One submit button opens two pages - one in a new window

Tags: javascript, forms, input, submit

I have a zip code submit button on my website. When user presses submit button I would like the current page (self) to go to a different page (of results) as well as a new tab / page opening. Here is what I am using. The problem I am having is that the second window does not open. Everything else works. I don't have much experience in coding. I've pieced this together through search.

```
<form id="header-box-form" action="http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/results.html" method="get">

    <input type="text" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)" maxlength="10" size="16" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" tabindex="1">

<input onmouseover=
                    "this.src='http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/pictures/orng_btn02.png';"
                          onmouseout="this.src='http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/pictures/orng_btn01.png';"
                          onclick=
                          "newWindow('http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/compare-rates.html','window2');window.open('http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/results.html','_self',' ')"
                          src="http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/pictures/orng_btn01.png"
                          type="image">

</form>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Is newWindow a function on your page?  Can we see it?

Comment: Hi Jim, What do you mean by is it a function on my page? Sorry but I'm a complete noob. The page this code is on is at www.quotesfortermlife.com/info. It is the quote box there in the header. The page opens to the results but the new window does not open as I am trying to get it to do.

Comment: The way you had newWindow in the onclick was like it was a function declared on your page.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
 onclick="javascript:window.open("http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/compare-rates.html","other_window")
```

to this

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.quotesfortermlife.com/compare-rates.html','other_window')
```

Firstly the "javascript:" part is wrong, it's only needed in a link's "href" attribute, this is misused a lot.  Secondly because you had a " around your URL it was closing the onclick attribute.  So lesson is to use single quotes if you have to quote inside a double quote.

Comment: @JimW, what about js? `document.form.button.onclick = function() {window.open(address1, address2);};` doesn't work

Comment: @yalov Is 'button' the name of your `<input>` element?  Is that code you pasted running *before* the page has loaded (if it is, then document.form.button won't exist yet).  Best thing is to create a new question with a jsfiddle.net setup in it.

Comment: @JimW, found a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732775/multiple-windows-using-window-open), but chrome-based browser blocks it by default. Apparently it isn't an appropriate user experience in 2017.