# Why is my jQuery function only opening one link and not the others listed in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm currently implementing a script into a website I'm working on that checks to see which checkboxes the user has checked and then once the user clicks submit it downloads said files. The issue I'm having is, no matter how many of the checkboxes are clicked, only the first file downloads and none of the others.

Here's my code:

```
// Global manual variables
var classic;
var racing;
var flexer;
// Global handbook variables
var classicEng;
var classicMulti;
var flexerEng;
var racerEng;

// Checkbox download function

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    classic = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-1');
    racing = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-2');
    flexer = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-3');
    classicEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-1');
    classicMulti = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-2');
    flexerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-3');
    racerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-4');

    jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {  
        if (classicEng.is(':checked') && classicMulti.is(':checked') && flexerEng.is(':checked') && racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked') && classicMulti.is(':checked') && flexerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked') && classicMulti.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked') && flexerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked') && racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank');  

        } else if (classicMulti.is(':checked') && flexerEng.is(':checked') && racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank');  

        } else if (classicMulti.is(':checked') && flexerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank'); 

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked') && racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank'); 

        } else if (flexerEng.is(':checked') && racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank'); 

        } else if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45-english.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-45.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (flexerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-45-english.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (racerEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-english.pdf', '_blank'); 

        } else if (classic.is(':checked') && racing.is(':checked') && flexer.is(':checked')) { 
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-parts.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classic.is(':checked') && flexer.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank'); 

        } else if (classic.is(':checked') && racing.is(":checked")) {  
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank')
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (racing.is(':checked') && flexer.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-parts.pdf', '_blank');
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (classic.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/classic-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (racing.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/racing-45-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        } else if (flexer.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/flexer-xl-parts.pdf', '_blank');

        }  else {
            alert("Please choose a file to download");
        }
    });
});
```

If someone could spot what I'm doing wrong here, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, chrome will automatically block your pop-ups. It did so for me.

Comment: You can also greatly reduce your code by using window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/'+filename, '_blank') . Setting filename in your if-else conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the Manual and Handbook variables being declared before the page has completed loading. I would recommend declaring them in the same place, but updating them inside the `jQuery(document).ready()`, which you can guarantee the elements have been rendered.

The resulting `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` would look like this:

```
    // Manual variables
    var classic;
    var racing;
    var flexer;

    // Handbook variables
    var classicEng;
    var classicMulti;
    var flexerEng;
    var racerEng;

    // Handbook download function
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            classic = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-1');
            racing = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-2');
            flexer = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-3');

            // Handbook variables
            classicEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-1');
            classicMulti = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-2');
            flexerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-3');
            racerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-4');

        jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {  
            if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
             } else if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (flexerEng.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (racerEng.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (classic.is(':checked')) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');        
            } else if (racing.is(":checked")) {        
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (flexer.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            }  else {
                alert("Please choose a file to download");
            }
        });
    });
```

The reason we continue to declare outside the `jQuery(document).ready()` but update them inside, is so that they remain global variables. If we had declared them inside the `jQuery(document).ready()` they would be out of scope for any function outside `jQuery(document).ready()`.

**In response to your follow up comments about making it able to download multiple files**, I would recommend making it push the names of the files into an array. Once you have pushed them into the array, you can iterate through them with a for loop and then fire off your calls, one by one.

Once again, if you were using a server-side code, you could add these separate files to one zip file to make it even easier for the user. The jQuery/Javascript would look something like this for the non-server-side solution:

```
        jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {
            var myArray = []
            if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
             }
             if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (flexerEng.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (racerEng.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (classic.is(':checked')) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');        
            }
             if (racing.is(":checked")) {        
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (flexer.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            }  
             //Find out how many files the user has selected
             var totalFiles = myArray.length;
             //Throw an error if no boxes are checked
             if (totalFiles == 0) {
                alert("Please choose a file to download");
             } else {
                     for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                           //Open a download window for each URL in the array
                           window.open(myArray[i]);
                     }
             }
            }
        });
    });
```

And now to briefly explain the new code. First, I declared an array called `myArray`. I changed your `if`/`else` statements to just `if` statements, and `push` (add) the URL of every checked box into the array.

Once the function has checked each box and added the URL to the array, I declare another variable called `totalItems` which checks the number of items pushed into the array. If there are no items in the array, I throw the `alert` that was in your `else` statement previously.

If there **are** items in your array, the `for` loop goes through each item separately and opens the download window for each.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thinking about it, you could use jQuery's `append()`, to append a separate `iframe` to the page for each and every file that the user wished to download. This could be within a `div` container that you hide using `display:none` in the CSS. Once you have appended it, change the src of each one to correspond with the file you wish to download and 'hey-presto' you have a download for each file without having to open a new window :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `if / else if`.  You need to use just `if` statements.  After the first true `if` or `else if` statement, all `else if` and `else` statements are skipped, so only one code block is executed in an `if / else if / else` structure.

Comment: To tag along with this answer, just having simple if statements open a new window will get all of the functionality you need. Opening a download link in a new window is a completely independent action of how many checkboxes are checked, and each case can be ignorant of the other cases!

Comment: I would probably structure the code differently too, but I don't see how it would solve the issue. If he just changed all of his `else if` to `if`, it'd give you duplicate files.

Comment: Hi @cameronroytaylor, I still don't understand how this would resolve the issue. Lets look at the first IF statement for example, which as you said if it's true it will ignore the elses below it (which is what I want it to do). Then why is it still only opening one download and not the others listed in that same IF statement?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the issue I'm having entirely. The issue is, whatever IF statement is correct, its only running the first line of code within that exact IF statement, and not the rest. I understand the elses will be ignored after the IF statement, that's the idea, as the user only wants the downloads they checked?

Comment: Hi @RyanColeman.  Are you wanting each checkbox to correspond to one download?

Comment: @RyanColeman So in the case of the first `if` statement, you are just having the first file download and the remaining 3 do not download?

Comment: Each checkbox is related to one file. For example, if the user clicks 'Racer' and 'Classic', then the IF statement which states (classic.is(':checked') && racing.is(":checked")) will become true, meaning the code within that IF statement should run (which is two download links via window.open)... But only the first opens.

Comment: Correct @cameronroytaylor, the remaining 3 are meant to download, but they do not, for some reason only the first file downloads and it seems to ignore the rest of the code in that IF statement which would initiate the 3 other downloads. This is the part I'm having an issue with, confusing as hell.

Comment: Have you tried giving them different window names, [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18732813/4541374)?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I was researching for around an hour and found that solution but it didn't help my issue out. I'm starting to think there maybe a better way of approaching the task, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: I'm able to get several windows to open without window names at all.  Have you run this without the `'_blank'` input?

Comment: I've tried that too, unfortunately, I do think it is just a pop-up blocking issue as other people have said. But as the page redirects so quickly it's hard to see what Chrome is blocking.

Comment: Try temporarily disabling pop-ups: Chrome > Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Pop-ups > Allow...

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `else if` . But also, most browsers will block opening new windows by default if you rapidly try to open new windows. Users will have to allow popups on their side.

Comment: I think the second part is the answer to the poster's question. Chrome will only open the first popup and block the others. It can be difficult to notice it since the "popup blocked" message is on the original tab. Even setting a timer between popups wont help.