# Open one or more multiple windows from javascript - no popup

Tags: javascript, html

I need to simply open to browser windows when user perform an action (to keep it simple in this example I use setTimeout).

I have notice that the browser is able to open only the first `window.open` and not the remaining.

What is the cause? How to fix it?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Worked fine for me on chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Windows using window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732775/multiple-windows-using-window-open)

Comment: I just tested it, it works on Chrome, but you have to enable popups (right side of the address bar)

Comment: sorry not user if it is the same question, as `Multiple Windows using window.open() ` use popup

Comment: @zerek the titles are similar but the contents of the question are different.

Comment: @George Okay, sorry^^

Comment: Just tried it on IE11 and firefox and both work fine as well. What browser are you using @Radex?

Comment: I have this problem on chrome, I had to enable popup to make it work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the windows unique, by default, the browser gives the new window a name, but doesn't dynamically update it when multiple instances of window.open occur (source - first line of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Give them unique names (with ids help) like so:

```
window.open('/path/to/page.php', 'UNIQUE_WINDOW1', 'width=300,height=400');
window.open('/path/to/page2.php', 'MORE_UNIQUE_WINDOW5', 'width=300,height=400');
```

if this doesn't work you can do:

```
window.open('/path/to/page.php');

$.post('/path/to/page2.php', {}, function(res)
{
    var win = window.open('', 'WINDOW_NAME', 'width=540,height=440');
    with(win)
    {
        open();
        write(res);
        close();
    }
});
```

what this will do is, post nothing to the page but, res returns the output of that file, so you assign window.open to a variable, and with it, open it and write the output to the file. :)

Comment: why downvote - I'm fine with it but leave explanation so I can improve :)