# How to Open Multiple URLs with Javascript in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

In a Cordova project (without InAppBrowser plugin), when I execute

```
window.open("http://foo.com", '_blank');
window.open("http://bar.com", '_blank');
```

only http://bar.com is opened.

How to open both URLs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Windows using window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732775/multiple-windows-using-window-open)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova documentation tells following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // external url
    var ref = window.open(encodeURI('http://apache.org'), '_blank', 'location=yes');
    // relative document
    ref = window.open('next.html', '_self');
}
```

Means it is possible to include external urls at not only one.

See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/inappbrowser/window.open.html

Comment: Just wanted to mention. Maybe this is helpful: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2132536