# How can open multiple URLs with single button click in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I want to make a button which the user can click and download all his/her files which are being fetched from the database. I have all download URLs in an array. 
Here is my code :

```
downloadFiles = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.state.AllFiles.map(file => {
         window.open(file.url)
    })
}

<div>
    All files for today: <a href="#" onClick={this.downloadFiles}>Download</a>
</div>
```

But this doesnt seem to work. It only opens the first URL and downloads that file but I want it to open all URLs. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried `forEach`?

Comment: forEach will work the same way. I am not able to open multiple links even if I hardcode it and not use loop. Like writing `window.open("url")` multiple times. It only executes the first `window.open()` and avoids the rest, idk why

Comment: Have you tried changing the `a` tag to a `button`? I'd also suggest removing the `e.preventDefault();` otherwise the browser might try to block popups.

Comment: Did you have a look at this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732775/multiple-windows-using-window-open/18733011 ? Seems like adding a different name on each open call may fix your problem

Comment: I tried using button without `e.preventDefault()` . Browser is still blocking the popups. If I disable popups block, multiple links are being opened.