# how to make button open 2 or more urls from diffrent checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

If checkbox (x) is checked go to Url x and if checkbox (y) is checked go to url y and if both are checked start them both.

This is what I am trying to do but only one of them work not both.

```js
function opentabs() {
  if (document.getElementById('WP1').checked) {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com/')
  }
  if (document.getElementById('WP2').checked) {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/')
  } else {
    alert("please check one program at least");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="WP1">Test Page 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="WP2">Test Page 1<br>
<button onclick="opentabs()">Open Tabs</button>
```

Comment: this worked for me? what is wrong with this code?

Comment: No both of them opened for me in new tab

Comment: Are you sure? Check if your browser  allows pop up tabs. Your code works fine.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732775/multiple-windows-using-window-open/18733011

Comment: if u select them both only one will open @AlirezaAhmadi

Comment: @O_N_K I think you need to check if your browser allows pop up tab or not. your code is fine

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi thx it was the browser ❤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine But you can check to see your browser **allows pop up tab** or not.

Note that most of browser does not allow for pop up tab by default and when you want to open a new link block new tab.

See [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) one to disable this item.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, you had another problem also. Your code doesn't have any problems.

```js
function opentabs() {
  if (document.getElementById('WP1').checked) {
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com/');
  };
  
  if (document.getElementById('WP2').checked) {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/');
  };
  
  if (!(document.getElementById('WP1').checked) && !(document.getElementById('WP2').checked)) {
    alert('please select at least one box');
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="WP1">Test Page 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="WP2">Test Page 1<br>
<button onclick="opentabs()">Open Tabs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Browsers can block several pop ups. A trick is to use a timeout on every tab openned.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //open your tab
},500);
```

Comment: I don't think it would be useful. Is this trick really useful? Can you describe more? I can't relate.

Comment: Yes, it works, I have used it in chrome-windows. Maybe the pop-up blocking has a time between them. Also recently I notice that does not work on chrome-apple m1

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```js
function opentabs() {
  if (document.getElementById('WP1').checked) {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('WP2').checked) {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/'
  }
  else {
    alert("please check one program at least");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="WP1">Test Page 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="WP2">Test Page 1<br>
<button onclick="opentabs()">Open Tabs</button>
```

Your code works as you wanted but firstly, you were using `if` instead of using `else if` after the first `if` statement, because of which when you were clicking on first button and then `Open Tabs` button the `alert` was called.

And also according to [Alireza Ahmadi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11359076/alireza-ahmadi) answer maybe your browser doesn't support `window.open` so instead of that you can use `window.location.href`